# The Summer GameJam! (2014) (Preparations)

Tags: discussion

The summer gamejam's going to start soon enough (in June), and I wanted to post this question here to ask people about an idea of mine and for any other suggestions they might have.

We did not have a theme restriction during the previous jam. This time, instead of going with another randomly chosen theme approach, I thought about this: each participant chooses a *gameplay* concept from an existing game, and builds a game around it, trying to give the concept a twist or making it better.

So a submission would look like:

1. The core concept and the game it originally belongs to.
2. How it was implemented in the participant's game and, if applicable, what the twist and/or improvement is.
3. The submitted game itself.

Drop some answers here if you disagree with my idea. Also drop answers with any other ideas you might have about the jam.

Comment: <3 buhhereowueh

Comment: @MickLH <3 hiya

Comment: YES!! ITS HAPPENGINGGNGNG! I MUST WIN GAME JAM BECAUSE I CANT RECEIVE MY T SHIRT THATS BEING TRANSPORTED TO MY US ADDRESS ATM

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your idea, could you please give an example? Maybe even an example game? For example, it's not obvious to me what separates the concept from its implementation. Would a game like Portal 2D or Mari0 count?

Comment: @congusbongus Portal 2D would count only if you chose 3-dimensional perspective based FPS as a concept. Which is not exactly an interesting choice if you ask me. A 2D portal-like game where... a portal changes your state before teleporting you is a good example. Say, a team-based game where going through a portal changes your team color. Something like that.

Answer (score 4):

I truly love your idea, in a way it's encouraging people to explore and find what's good out there. While preventing people to do exact copies. the only problem I've got with it's time span. can't you wait till July? I mean most students (like me) have final exams during June.

Comment: We could start it on the 4th of July, yes.

Comment: exam schedule, I think, depends. I am already on my exam week here. The varying exam schedule, I think, is more the case here since many of us are from many different parts of many different country.