# Organizer for the Summer Game Jam

Tags: discussion

Alex did a reasonable job of organizing the spring jam; however, in light of recent events, he no longer has full access to the community. I don't think it's in the jam's best interests to keep Alex as the lead organizer. The ability to chat with potential contestants and spread the word about the competition is vital to the success of game jams.

I suggest we have a vote for a new jam coordinator. [The summer jam's preparations](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/the-summer-gamejam-2014-preparations) are under way, and the date is tentatively set for the weekend of July 5th-6th, so we only have a few short weeks before things get underway. Get your votes in before [June 15th @00:00:00Z](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2014&month=6&day=15&hour=0&min=0&sec=0&p1=179&p2=64&p3=137&p4=33&p5=240&p6=2&p7=37).

What we're looking for in a new coordinator is:

- Effective communication skills
- Involved in the community
- Organization skills

If you're interested in becoming the new game jam coordinator, say a few words below.

Comment: Uh, I've only been banned from chat, something that never really helped with organizing the jams. But if you feel like taking the lead, please do.

Comment: @AlexM. If you feel like you can still run them, post your reasoning as an answer below.

Comment: Ultimately meta was the primary tool in organizing the jam itself, but I'd argue that chat was a tool that we used to contribute real time feedback about the jam and its meta posts before and after the posts were made. Certainly meta alone can be used to organize the jam but you can't disagree that the feedback you received in chat was useless.

Comment: Honestly, I could go either way on this as long as a jam does get organized. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will volunteer to organize these game jams. I've competed in every jam to date, and I'm frequently available in chat.

Considering my jam success, it could be a little weird for me to also run the jams. Please consider this before voting for me. I don't want anyone to feel like I'm altering the jams in my favour.

Comment: the jam itself is almost run by community. I mean the coordinator doesn't have any special privileges, well, maybe except picking a random theme based on the highest voted themes. But that's no big deal! I can trust you, picking the random theme. besides that we are all equal!

Comment: Yeah, it comes to picking the theme, making sure everyone knows when it starts, creating the thread(s), etc.

Comment: +1 I trust you. Electing an authority curbs [diffusion of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility) and ensures all the important things get done.