# The 2014 GDSE Summer Game Jam

Tags: discussion, gamejam

## Congratulations, everyone!

The jam has ended, and the voting has started already. Check out the answers to this question and the games inside them, and vote them up if you think they deserve it. **Downvotes are fine if that's how you want to vote, but at least leave a comment so the creators know how they should improve.**

The voting will end on [Sunday, July 13th, at 00:00 UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=GDSE+Summer+Game+Jam+2014+Voting+Closes&iso=20140713T00&p1=1440) (7 days after the end of the competition, minus a few hours so that I can be awake to close it)

If you wanted to participate but didn't have the chance, don't be sad! There will be another jam in the fall!

Original text:

> ## Time
>
> The summer Game Jam will take place between [July 4th
>   5am](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?p1=1440&iso=20140704T05&msg=GDSE%20Summer%20Game%20Jam%202014&sort=2)
>   and [July 7th
>   7am](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?p1=1440&iso=20140707T07&msg=GDSE%20Summer%20Game%20Jam%202014&sort=2)
>   UTC.
>
> ## Rules
>
> We're going to keep the same rules as before:
>
> - Participants are allowed to write games for any platform.
> - All publicly available libraries and middleware are allowed. All publicly available creation tools (e.g. Photoshop or 3DS Max) are
>     allowed.
> - The entrant is allowed use any premade assets as long as they're freely available on the web and the licenses allow them to be used in
>     an open source project (e.g. opengameart.org).
> - Assets created by the entrant during the game jam may also be used.
> - The forming of teams is not allowed.
> - Each entrant may ask questions on the main gamedev.stackexchange site, as long as the questions are on-topic as per normal site rules.
>     Alternatively, the chatroom may also be used.
> - Each entrant must release their game as open source after attaching a license of their choice.
>
> ## Theme
>
> The theme will be a bit different this time: each participant chooses
>   a gameplay concept from an existing game, and builds a game around it,
>   trying to give the concept a twist or make it better.
>
> A submission would look like:
>
> 1. The core concept and the game it originally belongs to.
> 2. How it was implemented in the participant's game and, if applicable, what the twist and/or improvement is.
> 3. The submitted game itself.
>
> Some examples would be: [Flappy
>   Golf](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/flappy-golf/id833756002?mt=8)
>   where they've taken Flappy Bird concept and moved it to a golf course.
>   I would argue that both 2D Portal and Mari0 also fit the bill.
>   Questions about the theme should be asked [over
>   here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/the-summer-gamejam-2014-preparations),
>   or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development).
>
> When your game is complete, add an answer here with a link to a
>   playable version, a link to the source, a screenshot or two, and how
>   your game fits the theme. Have fun!

Comment: It's happening!!!!!!

Comment: [*A wild logo appears!*](http://i.imgur.com/Ke4LQul.png) (No jam in it this time, because it's ice cream hunting season and my favourite flavour is game development.)

Comment: Super excited for this, it'll not only be my first jam with GDSE, but my first jam EVER! Good luck to everyone and may the best game win.

Comment: Same here. 1st GDSE Jam. 1st Jam. So say we all.

Comment: Added to compohub: http://compohub.net/jams/2014/2014-gdse-summer-game-jam/
Good luck everyone and make sure you submit a game, don't be shy!

Comment: Awesome turnout!

Comment: Woo, this is awesome. Congratulations to all who finished.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**Trap it!**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wBHa/22/)

Base Game: [Pathery](http://pathery.com), [Max and the magic marker](http://maxandthemagicmarker.com/)
Platform: jsfiddle?
twist: way too much to explain!
[Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/2wBHa/22/), Licensed under [CC-BY-NC-4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/)

I've started developing this game, based on grids, and thinking of bomberman but after a little while I thought why grids? so anyway, this is how it turned out!

By the way jsfiddle seems to fail, way more than my code. so if you want to test it on older browsers you've got to patch things together yourself!

**edit:** changed a rules a little bit, so they'll be more sane!
**edit2:** fixed a bug that caused an upper bound on the score (you couldn't get higher than 5056)

Comment: Pretty fun. An indication of how much line is left, or how soon you're going to get more line would help a lot.

Comment: @JohnMcDonald check again, changed the rules a little bit!

Comment: 5065! I think I can do better though... very fun! :D

Comment: @SpartanDonut that's actually a good high score!

Comment: I cheated and got out my stylus. I found with the mouse I kept failing to close my circles around the first few that would pop up.

Comment: Woop! Got 5114. Very nice concept.

Comment: I got up to almost 5360 myself. after the bug fix of course.

Comment: Awesome, the new mechanic is great! Good job!

Comment: Neat stuff here!

Comment: 6054. *mic drop*

Comment: Congratulations! You have won the 2014 Summer Game Jam!

Answer (score 12):

Participant: Kevin van der Velden

Platform: Python 3 and libTCOD

Based on game: [Magicka](http://www.magickagame.com/) from Paradox Interactive

Hey people, my first game I made for a game jam! :D

I liked the mechanic in Magicka where you could combine elements to create different spells, but I thought it could be improved a bit. You press the buttons 1 through 4 to create an orb (Water, Fire, Earth, Air). You launch these orbs by clicking where you want them to go.

If they collide with an enemy, the enemy get's hurt. If they collide with you... so do you!  But if they collide with a different orb there's a reaction, Fire and Air hitting each other creates Lightning orbs, Lightning and Earth hitting each other... destroys both of the orbs.

This is a turn based game, think about where to send your orbs and where to step to avoid getting hit, it gets hectic quite fast.

The objective of the game is to... survive, your orbs aren't peculiar about who they hurt and your HP is limited, try to get a high score! - I can't really get over 200.

[image: A gif of me playing the game](Full version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d21C.gif)

There's plenty more orb options to build in, and a lot of tidying up, which I might get to sometime after the jam, but for now I think it's done.

The py2exe windows version is available via Dropbox, nothing extra required, just unzip somewhere and run the .exe:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1193507/MagiOnslaught.zip

I've put the code on github and if anyone wants to help they're welcome: https://github.com/KevinVDVelden/MagiOnslaught

The version on github uses cygwin and has version 1.5.2 of libtcod, the py2exe version uses the MSVC build of libtcod which is version 1.5.1. The github version should work on linux if you install libtcod.

Comment: it's way too slow on my laptop, any ideas?

Comment: If you run it from the command line there's a --profile flag that'd  show you where time is spent, if you could post that I might be able to do some optimization.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't help, but still here is my console log:

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\MagiOnslaught>MagiOnslaught.exe --profile
24 bits font.


key color : 0 0 0


24bits greyscale font. converting to 32bits


Aborting merge.


Trying to remove entity [Entity 384 {Renderable 15}/{Position 450/71}/{Renderable 15}/{SpellComponent 0x4C282B}] but it's not in the list


Aborting merge.


Trying to remove entity [Entity 384 {Renderable 15}/{Position 450/71}/{Renderable 15}/{SpellComponent 0x4C282B}] but it's not in the list

Comment: Uuh weird, that's not the profile log (that's just the "This is a gamejam PRINT DEBUG ALL THE THINGS" output) - I may have removed the profile option =[

Answer (score 11):

### [Skippy Fish](http://skippyfish.jcpmcdonald.com/)

[image: Skippy Fish]

## [Play Now](http://skippyfish.jcpmcdonald.com/)

**Base Game**: Flappy Bird

**Concept Used**: Tap to stay in the air? Punishing, but quick

**Twist**: Instead of obstacles, well-timed taps are required to stay up

[Source Code](https://bitbucket.org/jcpmcdonald/skippy-fish/src), Licensed under [CC-BY-NC-4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/)

All art and sound assets were created by me, specifically for this project. I used Inkscape for the graphics, and a glass of water, a straw, some popsicle sticks, my own voice, and Audacity for the audio. I have uploaded all of these [assets to opengameart.org](http://opengameart.org/content/skippy-fish-assets) under more permissive licenses than the game.

Libraries used: CraftyJS, TweenJS, jQuery, Bootstrap, and jQueryUI.

Lobster font from [Google's Free Font Library](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lobster)

**Known issue**: Sound may not function properly in IE11, use Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I kinda can't figure out when should I press the button? I mean when entering the water, or before it?

Comment: @Ali.S, sorry, I guess it's obvious to the designer. I've added instructions on the play page now: Press or release the left mouse button as Skipper gets close to the surface of the water to skip. The goal is to stay out of the water as long as possible. Perfect > Great > Good > Poor. Perfect is somewhere just below the water's surface, and it goes out from there.

Answer (score 9):

### [The Dungeon](http://intellisenseless.com/TheDungeon)

[image]

[Click to play!](http://intellisenseless.com/TheDungeon)

**Game Description**

The Dungeon is a 2D Action RPG taking after the 2D Zelda Games. This game is but a fraction of what I actually wanted to do but I bit off more than I could chew. That said I feel like I managed scope / cut features appropriately and ended up with this, which for the moment, I am quite proud of.

The bulk of the art assets were taken off of OpenGameArt.org including the main tilesets and the music. Sound Effects and other art assets were created by me. The game was developed using Unity3D and its built in 2D features using C# as the programming language.

**Base Game**: 
The Legend of Zelda

**Concept Used**: Core 2D Action RPG gameplay mechanics

**The Twist**: The whole game is a single dungeon adventure

**Platform**: Web / Unity

**Source**: http://git.intellisenseless.com/SpartanDonut/the-dungeon/tree/master

**Credits / License**: http://git.intellisenseless.com/SpartanDonut/the-dungeon/blob/master/LicenseAndCredits.txt

Thanks for playing!

Comment: For what its worth, the boss fight is the highlight. If you think you fought the boss but aren't sure it was probably just a miniboss as there are a few throughout the dungeon (more like big minions than mini bosses actually). The room leading up to the boss fight makes it pretty clear what you are about to get yourself into. When you defeat the boss you will be awarded with a victory screen and music!

Comment: Those of you struggling (or bored) trying to reach the end I've added a secret to rush you to the boss. In the first 4 door room, right when you enter the dungeon, knock on the north door 5-10 times and it should open right up for you. If it's not opening and you played the game before, you might have a cached version before this was added.

Comment: This is quite fun :D

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[**Aes0p**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdzzy12fk2zljrd/Jam%20Entry.zip)

**Core game:** Frogger

**Twist**: Time manipulation

**Description**: You play as a hare trying to make your way through as many levels of roads and rivers as possible. Along the way, you'll be able to collect hourglasses which activate 'TURTLE TIME,' turn into a tortoise, and rip apart time by slowing most objects down.

**Source:** [github](https://github.com/hasherr/GDSESummerJam2014)

**Tech used:** Java 7, LibGDX, Paint.NET

**Run instructions:**

*NOTICE: You MUST have Java 7 or higher to run this game.*

1. Download .zip file, unzip at preferred location
2. Open file, click on GDSESummerJam2014_jar.jar, it will run and start the game

**Alternate**

1. Download .zip file, unzip at preferred location
2. Open command prompt, cd into location of .jar
3. Type `java -jar GDSESummerJam2014_jar.jar`

[**Credits**](http://pastebin.com/zG85vRuD)

Answer (score 8):

## [Dishes, Please](http://jeremyeastwood.com/)

[image]

**Concept:** My concept is based off of the processing of passport documents under a time constraint in Papers, Please.

**Implementation:** In Dishes, Please, you process dirty dishes by washing as many as you can during your shift. You need to watch the clock to know when your 12:00 to 6:00 shift will end.

**Known Issues:**

- Dish rotation is clunky and overly difficult to operate.

[**Play Now**](http://jeremyeastwood.com/)

[**Source on Github**](https://github.com/Costava/Dishes-Please)

Comment: I had weird input issues when trying the game (space bar didn't rotate and the water wasn't doing a good job at removing anything) but I enjoy the concept. :)

Comment: @SpartanDonut Thanks for playing my game! Dish rotation is known to be clunky, but should still be usable. Were you holding down space bar and moving the mouse?

Comment: Oooooooh. That's much better lol.

Comment: Well done! The concept really travels well from Papers Please.

Answer (score 7):

## Resident Zombies

[image: Screen shot]

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXgVbNnlb7s

### [PC Installer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9100066/GameJamClassicThunder.zip) ([Source Code](https://bitbucket.org/ClassicThunder/ruminate-framework/overview))

.

Base Game: The Binding of Issac

Concept Used: I've always felt the game-play in BoI was sluggish/clumsy and I figured it would be fun to merge the rouge like elements with traditional shoot-em-up gameplay.

Twist: Instead of plodding along slowly trying to dodge projectiles with odd pats, collision is obvious and you can move very quickly.

Source Code, Licensed under CC BY-NC-ND 4.0

All the artwork was described as free to use and scrounged together from across the internet.

- All character sprites were created by [DoubleLeggy](http://doubleleggy.deviantart.com/) ([A](http://www.deviantart.com/art/RE3-Monster-Sprites-v1-0-149653953)) ([B](http://doubleleggy.deviantart.com/art/RE-Side-Character-Sprites-v1-0-151126630))
- The room Tiles Set was created by [Daniel Cook](http://www.lostgarden.com/) ([A](http://www.lostgarden.com/2006/07/more-free-game-graphics.html))
- Sound effects thanks to [as3sfxr](http://www.superflashbros.net/as3sfxr/)
- Background music by [Crazy Games](http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Crazy_Games/) ([Song Used](http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Crazy_Games/Micro_Invasion_-_East_Jakarta_Chiptunes_Compilation/02_Micro_Invasion_-_Crazy_Games_-_Wake_Up))

Libraries used: [Ruminate Framework](https://bitbucket.org/ClassicThunder/ruminate-framework), [MicroStar](http://microstar.codeplex.com/)

Known issue: No way to restart in game. Have to relaunch it I'm afraid. No gamepad support :'(

Comment: Needs gamepad support ;)

Comment: Very true. I think I will make make another pass at the game soon to add some of the basics I skipped for times sake.

Answer (score 6):

## [Flap To The Future (click here to play)](http://kyunghwan.weebly.com/gamejamflaptothefuture.html)

[image]

Concept : one button "flappy bird" flying game.

Twist : Right mouse button now undos your action; you can rewind back.

All the art assets, except the main character from the game Braid are created by me.

Playform : Unity

Source : https://github.com/kyung01/GameJam_FlapToTheFuture

Thought :

Flappy bird is known for its forgiving gameplay style. Many people seemed to be frustrated by the gameplay. Since this Jam is to give twist/improve a gameplay concept, I decided to make Flappy bird "easier" by combining the flappy bird game with more forgiving game play concept.

Comment: I lost 10 minutes of precious time of working to just laughing hysterically at your sound effects. 10/10. Thank you.

Comment: Jesus the sounds... they're just too much :P

Comment: @hasherr ty hehehe glad you enjoyed it.

Comment: @Blue lol yes. Sound makes almost half of the game lel. :P

Comment: Where can I download the soundtrack?

Comment: @AlexM. All the sound files used in game are available here : https://github.com/kyung01/GameJam_FlapToTheFuture/tree/master/Assets/Audio For more information, and if you are interested in the artists work, contact The Mighty BlueBug.

Answer (score 6):

### [Bond That Atom](https://bitbucket.org/Lokkij/gdse-summer-gamejam-2014/downloads)

[image: Aww yeah, bond those freaking atoms.]

**Concept:** SpaceChem and Solar. It started off as reverse SpaceChem (let's make everything chaotic instead of logical!), and picked up Solar's concept of a floating entity picking up other floating entities.

**Technologies used:** Unity, [OpenGUI](https://github.com/mrzapp/opengui).

**Source:** you can find the source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/Lokkij/gdse-summer-gamejam-2014/overview).

All art except the GUI was created by me. You can find the GUI [here](https://github.com/mrzapp/opengui). So yeah, my first jam game ever! I think it turned out decently, especially for my first jam. It was a very fun experience, and I learned a surprising amount of things. And in case you missed the one in the title, [here](https://bitbucket.org/Lokkij/gdse-summer-gamejam-2014/downloads)'s another download link.

Comment: you should change the way you hint players what to build. I mean I don't know which atom should be connected to which

Comment: @Ali.S I have updated the downloads with a small in-game helpdesk. It probably won't make much sense never took chemistry classes, but it might refresh your memory if you did. In case updating the game a few hours after the deadline disqualifies my game, I can still revert it to the original build.

Comment: It seems I introduced a bug which causes the timer to progress 3x faster, making the game extremely difficult. That's fixed now. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Super Bounce](http://superbouncegame.com/)

[image]

## [Play Now (download)](http://superbouncegame.com/)

#### Use the following email to register Coherent when it pops up:

> registercoherent@superbouncegame.com

---

**Core Concept and Game:** Halo 2, [Super Bouncing](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Super_bouncing). Land on a mesh edge to with a "crouch" to soar to incredible heights

**Implementation:** No twist, just an awesome implementation of the original mechanic.

## [Source: GitHub](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Super-Bounce)

Built from the awesome Unity reference project [Radius](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Radius) that I authored.

[image]

Comment: [Jumping Flash](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyQI10yfl1E)!

Answer (score 5):

Participant: joapet99

Platform: Unity Web Player

Based On Game: Goat Petting Simulator on GameJolt.com

Open Source License: CC BY 3.0

[image]

Hey Guys! I wasn't really aware of this jam before just some days before it began. I really didn't know what to make. That night I watched a youtuber play a ton of simulator games and with them Goat Petting Simulator. I suddenly got the idea of basing my game jam entry on that game. Goat Petting Simulator is just about petting a goat, there is no goal or winning or losing. In the beginning I felt like it was going to be really stupid, but it turned out to be an acceptable game called Box Petting Simulator. I have gotten nice comments on it and the developer of Goat Petting Simulator himself has commented that my game is better.

There are way this and the original game is made is alike. Both are made in unity. And the concept is there. The thing is that in my game there is some improvements :D You have six boxes. You get one petting point by petting it gently. If you are not gently you destroy it. The game is over when all the boxes are "killed". You can submit the highscore as a user at gamejolt, as a guest or don't submit at all.

The controls are really easy. Move with WASD or arrow keys. Move the arm by moving the camera. And if you need more explanation you can click buttons which appears and write in textareas.

And now the moment you all have been waiting for! The link:

http://gamejolt.com/games/other/box-petting-simulator/29271/

For those who are interested in what I used I have a dropbox folder here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jxc89x4vlgqiffp/AAB5OKKuhwUPtUWtv7JbajVva

I have used a unitys Standard Assets and a hand asset too. I can't post link to hand asset since I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: I wanted to love it because it sounded hilarious but I didn't manage to get a single point. I really struggled to properly gauge at what depth the arm was at. I kept smashing into the boxes even though it didn't look like I should :(

Comment: i managed to get a personal best high score of 4! but i think the addition of some in game "guide" or instructions would go a long way. just explaining the logic on a box kill verses a box pet

Comment: Sound effects would take this to the next level. A pair of simple sounds would really make this game pop: a "successful petting" sound (like a pleasant goat bleat), and a "you killed me!" sound (something like a goat scream). This could really one-up the comedy in the game.

Comment: @Joe I have said this in the entry:  You get one petting point by petting it gently. If you are not gently you destroy it.
Isn't that enough to decribe?

Comment: @JohnMcDonald There is sound effects!

Comment: How did I miss those!?! Awesome

Comment: so i guess i was curious if 'pet' was defined by a physics force, or if i had to make contact with multiple faces, or some other definition.  i will admit i did not play for hours but i did 5 or so games, and i couldn't figure out "the trick" to the mechanic.

Comment: LOL @Joe it is in an OnCollisionExit method that it triggers

Comment: This game needs a sprint feature. As of right now it takes forever to explore the world. -1

Answer (score 5):

## "Continuum" - [PLAY NOW](http://josephjaniga.com/Continuum/)

[image: big boss fight]

- This learning exercise was based on the time travel concept from the game Braid.
- Built using the unity2d game engine and C# scripting **(both firsts for me)**
- My ultimate goal was to learn something about game dev and after many trials and tribulations, came up with a plan to try and attempt a "big boss fight" platformer on top of that time travel mechanic.

Sadly i did fall quite short of my super ambitious goal for my first game, still plenty of bugs, and incomplete features.  overall i consider this attempt quite incomplete, but still a success! the list of things i learned in this process has been enormous.

## So i learned a ton in this process and just wanted to give a big thanks to everyone in the chat for lending a hand! GDSE you all have been a huge help! can't wait until the next jam!

Controls:

- WASD - Player Movement
- SPACE - Jump (multi jump enabled presently)
- Left Click - "Shoot" (still broken *sadface*)
- Left Shift - Holding this will Reverse Time

the Repository - [Continuum Github Repo](https://github.com/josephjaniga/GDSE-2014-GameJam)